# React constructor зменение константы в конструкторе из дочернего компонента

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Здраствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста можно ли вообще изменять константы объявленые в конструкторе? если да то как?)
я хочу чтобы в const html записывались данные из дочернего элемента, но что-то вообще не выходит, направьте на правильный путь)

```
export default class EditorConvertToHTML extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      const html = 'test';
      const contentBlock = htmlToDraft(html);

      const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlock.contentBlocks);
      const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
      this.state = {
        editorState,
        textName: '123',
        textContent: '',
        content1: '',
        content : []
      };

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых: изменять константы нельзя, на то они и константы. 
Во-вторых: подумайте сами, конструктор родительского элемента вызывается самый первый, когда дочерних элементов еще и нет ( даже родительского `render` еще не вызвалось ), как тогда получить данные того чего нет?

В вашем случае, лучше повесить некий коллбек на хук `componentDidMount` дочернего элемента и в родительском обрабатывать.

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.onCreate(/* данные */);
    }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
    onChildCreate = (childData) => {
        // гуляем тут во всю
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Child onCreate={this.onChildCreate} />
        )
    }
}
```

Можно еще один подход сделать, сам хук `componentDidMount` вызывается, когда компонет и его дочерние элементы отрисовались первый раз ( то есть уже есть доступ к дочерним элементам ), но в этом случае, нам самим придется получать данные из дочерних компонентов

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const {children} = this.props
        // массив с дочерними компонентам
        // children[0].props
    }
}
```

Но такой подход сильно нарушает изолированность, так как теперь `Parent` завязан на `API` дочерних компонентов